# Can the Pi 3's internal Wi-Fi chip act as an Access Point?

Tags: wifi, pi-3

[From what I can find](https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/raspberry-pi-3-specs-benchmarks/), the internal Wi-Fi chip on the pi 3 is a *custom*
Broadcom BCM43438.

Is it capable of operating in AP mode?

Comment: I am hoping to get direct confirmation from someone who actually has one in hand and has successfully got it to work in this capacity.

Comment: how is the link I shared not confirmation? The author "directly confirms" they have it working, and walks through how to do it. Are you simply looking for someone to post "yes, I have done it" as an answer? That would provide no additional confirmation than what the post already says.

Comment: An answer posted here saying "Yes I did it" would be no more a primary source than the blog post (though technically both *are* [primary sources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_source)). There's nothing special about Stack Exchange contributors, they're "random people" just as much as the blog author is. Have you tried installing `hostapd` and `dnsmasq`? It should be fairly straightforward for you to verify yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [this article](https://frillip.com/using-your-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-with-hostapd/) yes you can:

> One of my first thoughts was, can I use it as a SoftAP for some ESP8266 sensor nodes? As it turns out, you can, and it's not that difficult, as the [BCM43438](https://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions/BCM4334) chip is supported by the open-source [`brcmfmac`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/brcm80211) driver!

You'll need to install two packages, [`hostapd`](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/hostapd) and [`dnsmasq`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), to get  a basic setup running (which the article walks you through), or [`isc-dhcp-server`](https://www.isc.org/downloads/dhcp/) and [`bind9`](http://www.bind9.net/) to get a more powerful and flexible setup.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @SteveRobillard what part of the question did I miss? It's simply asking if it's possible. I said it is, and provided a citation.

Comment: Good answers go beyond the sometimes simple question to the underlying question. Ask yourself this what is the users next question likely to be. Second, a link is subject to link rot, and hence  your answer is only as good as the link.

Comment: Whilst your link may answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the linked page here, as well as providing the link for citation. As such, this is a link only answer, and links tend to die over time, which will drastically reduce the usefulness of your answer. Please see the stack exchange policy on link only answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer. If you could edit your answer to include the relevant information, then that would be great.

Comment: @SteveRobillard I've added a quote; thoughts?

Comment: That is better but again, once the OP installs the package what if any configuration needs to be done? Or does it just work autiomatically.

Comment: @SteveRobillard It seemed inappropriate to simply copy the instructions from the linked article.

Comment: you can summaries and attribute the source, just like you would do in a paper for school.

Comment: You may even be able to improve on it (e.g. pointing out potential pitfalls or security issues, changes that would make it easier).

Answer (score 1):

You can see the full command line process of setting up the pi3 in a gist here https://gist.github.com/Lewiscowles1986/fecd4de0b45b2029c390

It does seem to have problems if the Pi3 is booted with other wlan attached on boot, so what I do is plug them in after boot (would love a solution to that problem)