# Raspberry Pi 3 - No Wifi

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-3

I just downloaded NOOBS 1.9 and then installed raspbian. During the install process NOOBS could connect to my WiFi. But once Raspbian booted, I get the message "no wireless interfaces found"

How do I get the built in WiFi to work?

Comment: What have you tried? How are you trying to configue it? In fact AFAIK none of the experienced users on this site use NOOBS, and have installed Raspbian directly.

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45003/can-the-pi-3s-internal-wi-fi-chip-act-as-an-access-point same problem

Comment: I re-installed Raspbian directly and WiFi worked out of the box.

Comment: I've experienced similar problems with a PI3 hooked up to the raspi-touch-lcd under rasping. WIFI worked until I installed the drivers for the LCD, as per instructions in the box. Booting from another SD card showed, that the problem was caused by software.